# Switch-statement inside a while-loop which loop infinitely

Tags: c++, while-loop, int, switch-statement

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int nothing;
    string name;
    int classnum;
    bool classchosen;
    string classname;

    cout << "Welcome adventurer, your journey is about to begin.\n\n";
    cout << "Firstly, what's your name? ";
    cin >> name;
    classchosen = false;
    while (classchosen == false)
    {
        cout << "\n\nNow, " << name << ", choose your class entering its number.\n\n";
        cout << "1- Warrior\n" << "2- Mage\n" << "3- Paladin\n" << "4- Monk\n\n";
        cout << "Class number: ";
        cin >> classnum;
        switch(classnum){
            case 1:
                    classname = "Warrior";
                    classchosen = true;
                    break;
            case 2:
                    classname = "Mage";
                    classchosen = true;
                    break;
            case 3:
                    classname = "Paladin";
                    classchosen = true;
                    break;
            case 4:
                    classname = "Monk";
                    classchosen = true;
                    break;
            default:
                    cout << "\nWrong choice, you have to enter a number between 1 and 4.\n" << endl;
                    break;
        }
    }
    cout << "\nSo you are a " << classname << " ? Well, tell me something more about you...\n";
    cin >> nothing;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, when I run it and input a string (for example "fjdfhdk") when it asks about the class number, the program loops infinitely instead of going in the default statement, writing again the question and letting me choose another class. Why?

Comment: Why does my program go into an infinite loop when someone enters an invalid input character: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/stream-input-failure.html

Comment: The problem is in the switch-statement though, it fails there, the infinite loop is a consequence of that and I don't know what to change there, it seems so logic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int getInt(const int defaultValue = -1){
  std::string input;
  cin >> input;
  stringstream stream(input);
  int result = defaultValue;
  if(stream >> result) return result;
  else return defaultValue;
```

}

```
//..in main
cout << "Class number: ";
int classNum = getInt();
switch(classNum){ .... }
```

The reason why it fails in your case is because cin is trying to read a bunch of chars into a int variable. You can either read it as a string and convert as necessary, or you can check the cin state explicitly when reading into a int variable by checking if any of the fail bits are set. The fail bits would be set if for example you try to read bunch of chars into an int.

Comment: I think this should probably do the trick, thanks, but it gives an error in: "stringstream stream(input.c_str());"

Comment: Nothing, it was std::stringstream ...
It works perfectly, thank you! :)

Comment: I totally agree with the basic principle here, but wouldn't it be better to use `std::getline` to extract the text from `std::cin`, rather than the `>>` operator.  In interactive input, this generally keeps the input and the prompts better synchronized.

Comment: Also, it's a nice touch to check that there's no trailing garbage in the line.  I'd use something like: `return stream >> result >> std::ws && stream.get() == EOF ? result : defaultValue;`

Comment: Yes. If we are expecting a user to input some data, the program should thoroughly make sure the input is properly formatted and is a valid input according to the specs. To do that, one could use getline and do post checking like you showed in the comments. However, for simplicity sake I omitted those checks. Thanks for noting them James!

Answer (score 1):

Because you're reading into an `int`, and the read fails.  This
has two effects:

1. your use of `classnum` afterwards is undefined behavior, and
2. the stream has memorized the error condition, so you can
   check it later.

As long as the error condition is not cleared, all further
operations on the stream are no-ops.  The simplest changes in
your program to make this work would be:

```
std::cin >> classnum;
if ( !std::cin ) {
    classnum = 0;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
}
switch ( classnum ) // ...
```

In case of an error, this sets `classnum` to a known value,
clears the error state, and skips all input up to the next
newline.  (Otherwise, you'll just fail again, because the
characters which triggered the error are still there.)

Consider, however, using a separate function to extract the int,
and using `getline`, as per user814628's suggestion.  The above
is more to explain to you what is happening, and why your see
the symptoms you see.  user814628's suggestion is far better
software engineering.